# Compare HDFS Checksum to Local File System Checksum

Tags: hdfs, md5, checksum

I am trying to write a simple script to verify the HDFS and local filesystem checksums.

On HDFS i get -

```
[m@x01tbipapp3a ~]$ hadoop fs -checksum /user/m/file.txt
/user/m/file.txt  MD5-of-0MD5-of-512CRC32C        **000002000000000000000000755ca25bd89d1a2d64990a68dedb5514**
```

On the Local File System, I get -

```
[m@x01tbipapp3a ~]$ cksum file.txt
**3802590149 26276247** file.txt
[m@x01tbipapp3a ~]$ md5sum file.txt
**c1aae0db584d72402d5bcf5cbc29134c**  file.txt
```

Now how do i compare them. I tried to convert the HDFS checksum from Hex to Decimal to see if it matches the chksum but it does not...

Is there a way to compare the 2 checksums using any algorithm?

thanks

Comment: I'm also doing same thing ..did you get solution?

Comment: Nope. The solution below of getting the File back and comparing is not practical for large files. Dont think there is any solution so far. I hope that HDFS Put does this sanity check somewhere

Comment: did you find any document which says this not possible for now ?

Comment: I tried the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31921022/5287221 and it did not work for me. Any ideas please?

Comment: I did find that there a patch for this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-12326

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Hadoop 3.1, checksums can be performed in HDFS. However, the comparison depends on how you `put` the file to HDFS in the first place. By default, HDFS uses CRC32C, which calculates MD5 of all MD5 checksums of individual chunks.

This means that you can't easily compare that checksum with one of a local copy. You can write the file initially with CRC32 checksum:

`hdfs dfs -Ddfs.checksum.type=CRC32 -put myFile /tmp`

Then, to get the checksum:

`hdfs dfs  -Ddfs.checksum.combine.mode=COMPOSITE_CRC -checksum /tmp/myFile`

For the local copy:

`crc32 myFile`

If you didn't upload the file with CRC32 checksum, or don't want to upload it again with CRC32 checksum, you can also just upload the local copy you want to compare with again with CRC32C checksum:

`hdfs dfs -put myFile /tmp`

And compare the two files on HDFS with:

`hdfs dfs -checksum /tmp/myFile` and `hdfs dfs -checksum /tmp/myOtherFile`.

---

Reference:

- https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Comparing-checksums-in-HDFS/ta-p/248617

Comment: I think this should be a selected answer. Because checksum is different by the platform we need to use the standard way.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution but a workaround which can be used.
Local File Checksum:
cksum test.txt

HDFS Checksum :
cksum `hadoop fs -cat /user/test/test.txt > tmp.txt` tmp.txt

You can compare them.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I was also confused because the md5 was not matching,turned out Hadoop checksum is not a simple md5, its a MD5 of MD5 of CRC32C :-)

see this

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hadoop-hdfs-user/201508.mbox/%3CCAMm20=5K+f3ArVtoo9qMSesjgd_opdcvnGiDTkd3jpn7SHkysg@mail.gmail.com%3E

and this

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hadoop-hdfs-user/201103.mbox/%3CAANLkTinR8zM2QUb+T-drAC6PDmwJm8qcdxL48hzxBNoi@mail.gmail.com%3E

Answer (score 1):

Piping the results of a cat'd hdfs file to md5sum worked for me:

```
$ hadoop fs -cat /path/to/hdfs/file.dat|md5sum
cb131cdba628676ce6942ee7dbeb9c0f  -

$ md5sum /path/to/localFilesystem/file.txt
cb131cdba628676ce6942ee7dbeb9c0f  /path/to/localFilesystem/file.txt
```

This would not be recommended for massive files.

Answer (score 0):

I used a workaround for this, created a simple script to compare checksum of local and hdfs file system using md5sum. I have mounted my hdfs file system as local /hdfs.

```
md5sum /hdfs/md5test/* | awk {'print $1'} > hdfsfile.txt
md5sum /test/* | awk {'print $1'} > localfile.txt
if ! diff /root/localfile.txt /root/hdfsfile.txt > /dev/null 2>&1;
then
/bin/mail -s "checksum difference between local and hdfs files" user@xyz.com < /dev/null
fi
```