# Checksum verification in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, checksum

Do we need to verify checksum after we move files to Hadoop (HDFS) from a Linux server through a Webhdfs ?

I would like to make sure the files on the HDFS have no corruption after they are copied. But is checking checksum necessary?

I read client does checksum before data is written to HDFS

Can somebody help me to understand how can I make sure that source file on Linux system is same as ingested file on Hdfs using webhdfs.

Answer (score 11):

If your goal is to compare two files residing on HDFS, I would not use "hdfs dfs -checksum URI" as in my case it generates different checksums for files with identical content.

In the below example I am comparing two files with the same content in different locations:

Old-school md5sum method returns the same checksum:

```
$ hdfs dfs -cat /project1/file.txt | md5sum
b9fdea463b1ce46fabc2958fc5f7644a  -

$ hdfs dfs -cat /project2/file.txt | md5sum
b9fdea463b1ce46fabc2958fc5f7644a  -
```

However, checksum generated on the HDFS is different for files with the same content:

```
$ hdfs dfs -checksum /project1/file.txt
0000020000000000000000003e50be59553b2ddaf401c575f8df6914

$ hdfs dfs -checksum /project2/file.txt
0000020000000000000000001952d653ccba138f0c4cd4209fbf8e2e
```

A bit puzzling as I would expect identical checksum to be generated against the identical content.

Comment: the checksums from HDFS are coming from the filesystem's underlying data; if you have different block sizes, encryption, erasure coding etc. these will be different. The checksums are *not* dynamically calculated

Comment: In case `md5sum` is not available  - one can try `cksum`

Comment: If the data is huge (which is the purpose of HDFS), downloading the whole content to the local machine for a local checksum is not a reliable solution.

Answer (score 9):

Checksum for a file can be calculated using hadoop fs command.

Usage: hadoop fs -checksum URI

Returns the checksum information of a file.

Example:

hadoop fs -checksum hdfs://nn1.example.com/file1
hadoop fs -checksum file:///path/in/linux/file1

Refer : [Hadoop documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#checksum) for more details

So if you want to comapre file1 in both linux and hdfs you can use above utility.

Comment: checksum of file on linux box and hdfs comes different

Comment: `hadoop fs -checksum file:///path/in/linux/file1` did not worked for me, it returns `NONE`. any ideas why?

Comment: Is your path 'file:///path/in/linux/file1' an hdfs path ?

Answer (score 7):

I wrote a library with which you can calculate the checksum of local file, just the way hadoop does it on hdfs files.

So, you can compare the checksum to cross check.
https://github.com/srch07/HDFSChecksumForLocalfile

Comment: What is the point of this, when you most likely have linux tools at hand for that ? For example: hdfs dfs -get | md5sum

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this check via API

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._
import org.apache.hadoop.io._
```

Option 1: for the value `b9fdea463b1ce46fabc2958fc5f7644a`

```
val md5:String = MD5Hash.digest(FileSystem.get(hadoopConfiguration).open(new Path("/project1/file.txt"))).toString
```

Option 2: for the value `3e50be59553b2ddaf401c575f8df6914`

```
val md5:String = FileSystem.get(hadoopConfiguration).getFileChecksum(new Path("/project1/file.txt"))).toString.split(":")(0)
```

Comment: Option 2 worked for me with one modification.  The entire string is something like  "MD5-of-0MD5-of-512CRC32C:2945923ab454345cd9073a", so to get the hash part of it I had to use .toString.split(":")(1) instead of .toString.split(":")(0)

Comment: What is hadoopConfiguration here ?

Answer (score 0):

It does crc check. For each and everyfile it create .crc to make sure there is no corruption.