# Data comparison after after migrating the file to hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm new to Hadoop. I have a source Excel file or any flat file and I want the same file to be moved from local file system to hdfs. After migration, I want to compare the two files to check whether data has been migrated correctly or not (file compariions program) to get the reports(mismatch of data for Reconciliation)
EX: Imagine I have some names in the Excel file after.

It would be great if anyone help me.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checksum verification in Hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31920033/checksum-verification-in-hadoop)

Answer (score 0):

Why not install an `hdfs` file browser like `Hue`. With this tool you should be able to view all the files inside `hdfs` from a GUI.

Comment: I can install but .But i'm working in data migration project. So i want how this can be done programatically.

Answer (score 0):

I also had similar use-case. 
You can do bytes count on source and target like below:

For local file system :

```
    du -h <source-file-path>
```

For hadoop location:

```
    Hadoop fs -du -h <hadoop-target-path>
```

If the data is loaded correctly then the byte size will match. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: That's is fine but i want to compare the data if there is any mismatch had happen.For ex in source file i have some data of customers.In First name column i have data like ram ,after migrating to hdfs due to some errors it might have changed to sam (ram to sam). I want this mismatches to be reported in some file.