# Generate md5sum which are stored in hdfs

Tags: javascript, hadoop, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

How to generate md5sum of the file contents which is present in Hadoop file system?

Below is the code which worked for the local file system but it didn't work if the file is present in HDFS

```
org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.md5Hex(new java.io.FileInputStream(filename))
```

For Example :

```
filename=hdfs://xyz/a/b/c/d.csv
```

Comment: Any suggestions

Comment: rather then using any external library you can use Add a checksum step inside pentaho transformation and select type as MD5, it wills solve your problem.

Comment: Whether it will calculate based on filename contents or filename

Comment: Moreover it is not similar value with how we do in linux md5sum function

Comment: check the step, you have to specify column names, based on that it creates sum.

Comment: The reason why i am not adding columns if my file is avro i don't want to get the column list of the avro file and pass to the checksum component it will increase unnecessary work. Is there any way like sample which is working in local

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31920033/checksum-verification-in-hadoop. Will that be useful?

Comment: I have seen this post but there are two import statements which i didn't get how to add in a single line like the exmaple shown above.. org.apache.hadoop.fs.MD5Hash.digest(FileSystem.get(hadoopConfiguration).open(new Path("/project1/file.txt"))).toString like this it didn't work. What is the value of hadoopConfiguration. It is not clear in that post